# mysql procedure calling another procedure

Tags: mysql

Is this possible in MySQL...

I have one proc called "doc_init" (inits a doc table)

I have another proc called "doc_xxx_init" (inits the doc_xxx table)

I need to call doc_xxx_init, then inside of there the first things it must do is call doc_init "call doc_init(a,b,c)", which returns a row.  My question is: How do I store that row so I can have access to certain column for the rest of my processing in doc_xxx_init?  In Oracle I would do something like this...

```
create or replace procedure doc_xxx_init....
tempRow doc%rowtype;
begin
tempRow := doc_init(a,b,c);
/*then from here on I could access that row like tempRow.id, or tempRow.anyColumn*/
```

I've seen plenty of examples of how to call one procedure from another, but not how to store the results like I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can't capture the output of stored procedures in MySQL.

You can, however, have `doc_init` create a temporary table, which can be accessed by the caller and hopefully disposed of appropriately.